# is 'using namespace' means load entire types under that namespace

Tags: c#, .net

say i have a code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class TestApp
{
   static void Main()
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Testing! 1, 2, 3");
     MessageBox.Show("Hello...");
   }
}
```

will the `using System` & `System.Windows.Forms` means load all types (within those namespaces) at runtime, although im using only to print on console and show a messagebox ?

and also will there be any memory consumed for loading those required types (`Console` & `MessageBox`) at the execution time...

[ and there will be some block of code (within `Console`) still unutilized by the source code but still will it be loaded ? ]

so any clue on what's happening behind the scenes (atleast for the above 10 lines of code)would be helpfull...

Comment: Yes. The DLLs containing types that you use will be loaded in memory. I think, merely a `using` statement doesn't load the DLL, unless it is used in the code.

Comment: means mscorlib.dll rit? but still it has tonnes of types still left unused rit?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: This is wrong. Nothing is loaded with a `using`. Assemblies are loaded before classes used. `using` makes it possible to use just the class name instead of the fully qualified name. See Joachim Isaksson's answer.

Comment: @xCoder: You are probably coming from Java - then you should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769025/difference-between-c-sharp-using-and-java-import

Comment: @joe: Please see Joachim's reply to my comments (under Joachim's answer below). It confirms what I have added above, to which you said - it is wrong.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: The comment does not contradict to mine. We are talking about two different things. 1) The [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) directive allows the use of types in the code. 2) assemblies are loaded when a type is used. So again: `using` does NOT cause a assembly load.

Comment: @joe: Isn't that (" I think, merely a using statement doesn't load the DLL, unless it is used in the code.") what I wrote? What is wrong with my 1st comment?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: sorry - i don't wanted to irritate you. I think we DO mean the saem thing...

Comment: @joe: Dont worry. I thought I could be wrong & hence checked with Joachim on my assumption hence.

Answer (score 7):

`using` statements are compile time only statements allowing the compiler to find referenced types without specifying the fully qualified name at every use, they will *not* make anything load at runtime that otherwise wouldn't load if referencing the same type directly.

Comment: In fact, they are there to expand types to their fully qualified names during compilation.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes, was just posting from an iPhone, so not the fastest typer :) Updated to qualify a bit more what it does.

Comment: basically it saves typing.  For instance, instead of typing `System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");`, Adding `using System.IO;` means you only need to type `File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");`.  It's basically up to the coder.

Comment: It's also required for the compiler to discover extension-methods. To use extension-methods as extension-methods (and not as static methods) actually require that the namespace is declared in a `using`-statement. I think that's the only time you are required to use a `using`-statement though.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I have a question. Do the DLLs get loaded, if you have referenced it but haven't used it in the code (either by `using` or a full name)? Thank you.

Comment: @shahkalpesh If you're doing "using" on a namespace in a DLL that you're not actually using in your code, the DLL won't be loaded at runtime. Namespaces can be split over multiple DLLs too, only the DLLs that contain code that you actually use will be loaded. The runtime doesn't even know about "using", so it couldn't load the DLLs you're "using" if it wanted.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Thank you for your reply. I wanted to confirm this as I have commented the same thing below the answer. However, I am told it is wrong in the following comment by Joe (which I believe is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Yes all types directly in the namespace, so nothing from sub namespaces. This means that having many usings increases compile* time. But it has no effect on runtime because by then there are no usings anymore and every namespace usage has been converted to a direct reference to the type.

*This means the part where it says 'loading symbols' and it actually does not always have to do this. So the big solution at my job takes 30 seconds to load all the symbols but most compiles are very fast because it doesn't have to reload the symbols.

edit @xCoder:
This has to do with how assembly works, there are no classes, just data. So the classes you use the higher level language each compile into different assembly code because the class handles data differently. C# uses IL instead of assembly and I'm not sure, but that probably works the similar.

Comment: <every namespace usage has been converted to a direct reference to the type> so the assembly should exist in memory so that referenced type is accessible to the source code rit?